# Zenity Bash List from file

Tags: linux, bash, file, zenity

I would like to get smt like this

[image]

And I have data with file, but I don't know how can I use it.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That's not enough information. What does your data file contents look like?

Comment: It will be like this (with the specific values, many lines)
Name, Title, Artist,Album,Year,Genre,Track,Comment

Comment: In other words, a comma-separated list, with exactly 8 entries per line? Can the title be something like `Crosby, Stills, Nash & Young` with commas? If so, how are the commas within a field escaped? What if a field is empty?

Comment: Field can not be empty. No, title is without comma or specials sign

Answer (score 0):

```
cat data.csv |          # get data from file
  sed '1 d' |           # delete csv header row
  tr ',' '\n' |         # put each csv field on a separate line
  zenity --list \
    --column=name \
    --column=title \
    --column=artist \
    --column=album \
    --column=year \
    --column=genre \
    --column=track \
    --column=comment    # render data in zenity dialog
```

**Assumption**: the fields don't contain commas.